# Rebus pub-sub system. Process each message by one and only one subscriber

Tags: rebus

With rebus, I'd like to be able to publish from one application, and subscribe from multiple applications, where each message only gets processed by one subscriber in a round robin, as described here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html

Is this possible with rebus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the words "publish" and "subscribe" are confusing here, because it's not ["Publish/Subscribe"](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PublishSubscribeChannel.html) as described in the literature, because pub/sub pretty much means that you do not care how many listeners there are.

What you want, is to *send* a message, and then you want the sent messages distributed among multiple consumers.

With Rebus, that is definitely possibly. However, the way you do it may depend slightly on which transport, you are using(*)

Most transports have pretty good support for the [competing consumers](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CompetingConsumers.html) pattern, where you simply start multiple processes, probably running on multiple machines, that consume messages from the same queue.

This way, each message gets processed exactly once, and each consumer will receive messages at a rate that suits that particular consumer.

---

(*) MSMQ is not good at distributing load when multiple processes are taking messages off of the same queue, especially not when the processes are running on other machines than where the queue is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes competing consumers is what we are aiming for. For prototyping we are using the filesystem, can it be done with that (and if so is there any documentation available on how)? Longer term it's likely to be azure service bus. Great work by the way, was nice to run up the pub-sub sample project and see it just work.

Comment: I actually think the file system transport handles competing consumer just fine, as it uses file locks to achieve exclusive access to the message files.

Comment: Great, so is there an OptionsConfigurer or something to enable this? I cant see anything obvious. My publisher setup looks like this: Configure.With(activator).Transport(t => t.UseFileSystem(@"C:\MyPath\TransportTest", "publisher"))
.Subscriptions(s => s.UseJsonFile(JsonFilePath))
.Start();

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry – I remembered wrong! When using the file system transport, you WILL have get multiple consumers receiving the same message if you start multiple Rebus endpoints with the same input queue.

Comment: oh thats a shame, well thanks for your help anyway :-)